# Perl: Install Filter::Crypto fails with 'No Openssl crypto library found'

Tags: perl, openssl, cygwin

I wanted to install Filter::Crypto (W10, cygwin, both current) via cpan. Failed. Results see below

```
Running install for module 'Filter::Crypto'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.084)
Checksum for /home/Wolfgang/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/Filter-Crypto-2.09.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.30)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200601_30)
Configuring S/SH/SHAY/Filter-Crypto-2.09.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Where is your OpenSSL? [/usr] /usr

Found include directory ............ /usr/include
Found OpenSSL version .............. 1.1.1f
Error (109): No OpenSSL crypto library found at Makefile.PL line 66.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  SHAY/Filter-Crypto-2.09.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
```

It seems to me, the algorithm to find the library is faulty, because a find yielded this:

```
$ find usr -iname '*crypto*' | grep -v python | grep -v '.3.gz'
usr/include/openssl/crypto.h
usr/include/openssl/cryptoerr.h
usr/include/w32api/windows.security.cryptography.h
usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/crypto.h
usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/openssl/crypto.h
usr/share/crypto-policies
usr/share/doc/crypto-policies
usr/share/man/man7/crypto-policies.7.gz
usr/share/man/man7/crypto.7.gz
usr/share/man/man8/update-crypto-policies.8.gz
usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/openssl/crypto.h
usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libcrypto.a
usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libcrypto.dll.a
usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
usr/bin/cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll
usr/bin/cygcrypto-1.1.dll
usr/bin/cygk5crypto-3.dll
usr/bin/update-crypto-policies
usr/lib/libcrypto.dll.a
usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
```

2021-01-15: Added print in probe_for_lib_file, passes through there just once when checking /usr/lib, which seems to be the default path if nothing else works:

```
Found include directory ............ /usr/include
Found OpenSSL version .............. 1.1.1f
Probing dir '/usr/lib', (config(cc) = gcc)
Error (109): No OpenSSL crypto library found at Makefile.PL line 66.
```

In this directory there is a file libssl.dll.a, but the package is not looking for that filename

If somebody could tell me what filename for the lib is expected, I would transfer the file there manually and try again

Searching for libssl shows several results, lines with year=2020 probably are the once with the best/current information

```
$ find /usr -iname '*libssl*' -ls
2814749768319286    580 -rw-r--r--   1  Wolfgang Kein       591578 Mar 28  2018 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libssl.a
2814749768319287    204 -rwxr-xr-x   1  Wolfgang Kein       208402 Mar 28  2018 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libssl.dll.a
2814749768319289      1 -rw-r--r--   1  Wolfgang Kein          344 Mar 28  2018 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
1970324837361655    664 -rwxr-xr-x   1  Wolfgang Kein       678966 Apr  8  2020 /usr/lib/libssl.dll.a
1970324837361657      1 -rw-r--r--   1  Wolfgang Kein          264 Apr  8  2020 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
```

Comment: Try adding some debugging prints before [line 1184](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/Filter-Crypto-2.09/Makefile.PL#L1184) to see which exact step failed.

Comment: The module installs fine here with Strawberry Perl 5.30.1 on Windows 10, I will test on Cygwin later.

Comment: What happens when you answer the question about OpenSSL with other paths, such as `/usr/include/openssl`? I wouldn't think `/usr` would be enough. For example, I have my in my environment `OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ssl`.

Comment: @choroba pointed to the routine ´locate_lib_dir_and_file´ which simply does not contain the directory-names where the module could be found. Additionally ´probe_for_lib_file´ explains the naming conventions that are expected (but not followed in this case by the current cygwin). So my guess is, that the only problem are the missing or wrong rules for cygwin - or cygwin does not follow the rules

Comment: @Wolfgang Good to hear that the patch solved your issue! Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

> So my guess is, that the only problem are the missing or wrong rules
> for cygwin - or cygwin does not follow the rules

Yes it seems the module does not support Cygwin yet. I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/steve-m-hay/Filter-Crypto/pull/4) that fixes the problem by patching `Makefile.PL`.